# Qt linker error while using QSerialPort library

Tags: c++, qt

For a programming class I need to connect my arduino to my Qt GUI with a serialport connection, but when i try defineing a port i get a lot of errors.
I am currently using Qt 5.7.

Header file

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void initPort();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSerialPort * arduino;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QObject>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    initPort();
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::initPort()
{

    arduino = new QSerialPort;
    return;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-11-02T13:48:06
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui serialport


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = LEDfade
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Errors:
[image: ERRORS]

Comment: You should try to copy and paste the errors in text here, if anyone is trying to find the possibly answered question later they can't find it with an image url.

Comment: Did you add "serialport" later on? Try "Build"->"Run qmake" and rebuild the project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Kevin the errors are included, just click ERRORS.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `qmake` under `Build -> Run` in qmake.
That will do the job.